# wrong result possibly because MergeAs(AppendOnly) LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

**NOTE**

This might be a dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077403/linq-to-entities-not-returning-expected-result). But I don't get a clear answer from that.

**The problem**

I got wrong result from linq.

**EXAMPLE**

```
id     groupid   status     name
------------------------------------
guid1  guidA     reserved   truck1
guid2  guidA     reserved   truck2
guid3  guidA     reserved   truck3
guid4  guidA     reserved   truck4

*assume all guids are guids.. 
**id is a primary key (unique)
```

**CASE**

If I put only `where groupid == guidA` the result is correct (4 rows)

but, if I put `where groupid == guidA && status == reserved` the result is wrong (3 rows)

**EXPLANATION**

The query built with expression tree. From the debug watch, the query (that return wrong the result) is like this

```cs
query.Expression:
-----------------
Convert(value(System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[myEFTable]))
.MergeAs(AppendOnly)
.Where(m => ( m.groupId == value(myFilterClass).groupId))
.Where(m => m.status.Contains(value(myFilterClass).statusStr))
.Select(m => new myViewClass() 
{
    Id = m.id, GroupId = m.groupid, Status = m.status, Name = m.name
})
.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Skip(0).Take(10)
```

Then I tried to run a similar query and it returns correct result

```cs
assume e is ObjectSet<myEFTable> and strGuid is guidA

Guid grId = new Guid(strGuid);
e.AsQueryable()
.Where(m => m.status.Contains("reserved"))
.Where(m => m.groupId == grId)
.Select(m => new myViewClass()
{
    Id = m.id, GroupId = m.groupid, Status = m.status, Name = m.name
}).OrderBy(o => o.Name).Skip(0).Take(10);
```

**QUESTION**

I'm completely clueless about this error..

1. If my EF tables are correct and the query is correct, why does it return wrong result?
2. Is it because the `MergeAs(AppendOnly)` ? because the only thing that different is that.
3. If this is about unique key, what should I do with `myViewClass` to ensure that every row is unique and should not be merged (if that was the case) ?

   ### ---------------------------------------------------------------------

**UPDATE 2013/08/29**

The result is incorrect because I have a typos in one of my query..

So, after changing few lot of here and there, try and error, till I almost lost the trace of whatever that changed, commented, erased, suddenly it works.. EUREKA!! what?

what I did is not really change everything, it's just a lot of changes but doesn't really end up so much different than where I was starting.. so there's that!

then that EUREKA moment ends and leave me tracing my way back to find out what is actually wrong, simply because I don't believe in miracles..

so here it is..

The tables is actually similar to this:

```
 PartsGroups   
 -----------
 id  name   
 -----------
 1   Nails  
 -----------

 Items
 -----------------
 id  name   status
 -----------------
 2  Table  Empty
 5  Table  Indent
 6  Door   Empty
 3  Sofa   Empty

 PartsGroupPairs      
 ------------------   
 id  groupId partId   
 ------------------   
 1       1       4    
 2       1       7    
 3       1       8    
 4       1      15    
 -------------------  

 Parts                      
 ------------------------   
 id  name  itemId  status   
 ------------------------   
  4  XNail      2  Empty    
  7  SNail      5  Empty    
  8  UNail      6  Empty    
 15  ZNail      3  Empty    
 ------------------------
```

The relationships is like this

```
 PartsGroups   PartsGroupPairs      Parts                      Items
 -----------   ------------------   ------------------------   -----------------
 id  name      id  groupId partId   id  name  itemId  status   id  name   status
 -----------   ------------------   ------------------------   -----------------
 1   Nails     1       1       4     4  XNail      2  Empty     2  Table  Empty
 1   Nails     2       1       7     7  SNail      5  Empty     5  Table  Indent
 1   Nails     3       1       8     8  UNail      6  Empty     6  Door   Empty
 1   Nails     4       1      15    15  ZNail      3  Empty     3  Sofa   Empty
 -----------   -------------------  ------------------------   -----------------
       One <---> Many       Many <---> One           Many <------> One 

 PartsGroup.pairs is a collection of PartsGroupPairs 
 PartsGroupPair.group is a PartsGroup 
 PartsGroupPair.part is a Part
 Part.item is an Item
 Item.parts is a collection of Parts
```

So when I select PartsGroup where name == 'Nails' it works perfectly, it returns 4 rows

But why when I select PartsGroup where name == 'Nails' and Status == 'Empty' it returns 3 rows?? (see below)

```
 PartsGroups   PartsGroupPairs      Parts                      Items
 -----------   ------------------   ------------------------   -----------------
 id  name      id  groupId partId   id  name  itemId  status   id  name   status
 -----------   ------------------   ------------------------   -----------------
 1   Nails     1       1       4     4  XNail      2  Empty     2  Table  Empty
 1   Nails     3       1       8     8  UNail      6  Empty     6  Door   Empty
 1   Nails     4       1      15    15  ZNail      3  Empty     3  Sofa   Empty
 -----------   -------------------  ------------------------   -----------------
```

this row didnt get selected..

```
 PartsGroups   PartsGroupPairs      Parts                      Items
 -----------   ------------------   ------------------------   -----------------
 id  name      id  groupId partId   id  name  itemId  status   id  name   status
 -----------   ------------------   ------------------------   -----------------
 1   Nails     2       1       7     7  SNail      5  Empty     5  Table  Indent
 -----------   -------------------  ------------------------   -----------------
```

the mistake I made is at the `Where` part. The query itself built at the runtime coz I separate entities, filters, views and paging modules. So mostly I just passing `IQueryable` here and there.

In the case for filter, every time I filter, I'll add another Where. So in this case it went like this below:

```cs
using(var DB = new databaseContext()) 
{
    ObjectSet<PartsGroupPair> d = 
        DB.CreateObjectSet<PartsGroupPair>("partsGroupPair");

    int searchGroupId = 1; // int instead of guid for example
    int searchStatus = "Empty"; 

    // filter by specific PartsGroup    
    IQueryable<PartsGroupPair> e = d.Where(m => m.group.id == searchGroupId);

    // then if I want to filter by the status
    e = e.Where(m => m.part.item.status == searchStatus));  // WRONG!! 
    // I want to filter by part.status, not item.status
    // so instead, it should be 
    e = e.Where(m => m.part.status == searchStatus));  // RIGHT!! 

    // view 
    IQueryable<PartsGroupPairView> f = 
        e.Select(m => new PartsGroupPairView()
        {
            Id = m.id, GroupId = m.groupid, 
            Status = m.part.status, Name = m.part.name 
            // etc..
        });

    // paging
    f = f.OrderBy(o => o.Name).Skip(0).Take(10);  
}
```

The wrong filtering makes LINQ ignore the other Parts, and returns 3 rows instead of 4 because it found only one Item instead of 2 Parts.

So in my case, it's a silly typo with a quite complex data..

It's really frustrating when nothing works while everything seems to be okay..

Comment: "AppendOnly is the default merge option."